# Python: Making a projectile bounce on the GraphWin window along all walls?

Tags: python, graphics, bounce

Extend the projectile and tracker to implement the following graphics game:

a. There is square box of a given dimension (choose one reasonable size box) in which 
there is a projectile which randomly bounces of the four walls.

b. When a projectile hits a wall, it is launched again by randomly selecting an angle in 
the allowed range and a random velocity in a given range. For example, if the 
projectile hits the bottom boundary, it selects a random angle in the range 0 to 180 
degrees; if it hits the right vertical wall then, it selects random angle between 90 and 
270 degrees; and so on.

c. Instead of drawing the circle, move the circle and also fill it with some color.

d. Extend to two projectiles.

Don't ask user the parameters. Use a set of parameters that you think the best.

So I am having trouble trying to find how to make two cballs (the projectiles) bounce from wall to wall. I figured how to bounce them off the bottom wall of the window but it doesn't stop at the right wall and bounce from there. Not only that I have no idea on how to make the balls follow instead of continuously printing circles to Track the movement of the balls. I use ".undraw()" but its very jumpy and not smooth at all.

I would appreciate the help very much! The assignment is due tomorrow and this is what i have:

```
# projectilebounce.py
#   Projectile hits a wall and again is launced

from math import sin, cos, radians

from graphics import *

class Projectile:

    def __init__(self, angle, velocity, height):
        self.xpos = 0.0
        self.ypos = height
        theta = radians(angle)
        self.xvel = velocity * cos(theta)
        self.yvel = velocity * sin(theta)

    def update(self, time):
        self.xpos = self.xpos + time * self.xvel
        yvel1 = self.yvel - 9.8 * time
        self.ypos = self.ypos + time * (self.yvel + yvel1) / 2.0
        self.yvel = yvel1

    def getY(self):
        return self.ypos

    def getX(self):
        return self.xpos

    def reset(self, angle, velocity, height):
        self.xpos = self.getX()
        self.ypos = height
        theta = radians(angle)
        self.xvel = velocity * cos(theta)
        self.yvel = velocity * sin(theta)


class Tracker:

    def __init__(self, window, objToTrack):
        self.win = window
        self.obj = objToTrack

    def update(self):
        a = Circle( Point(self.obj.getX(), self.obj.getY()), 5)
        a.draw(self.win)
        a.setFill("Black")
        a.undraw()


def getInputs():
    a1 = 60
    a2 = 30
    v1 = 60
    v2 = 60
    h1 = 10
    h2 = 10
    t = 0.1
    return a1, a2, v1, v2, h1, h2, t

def main():
    print("This program graphically depicts the flight of a cannonball.\n")

    win = GraphWin("TRACKER", 600, 500)
    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 600, 500)

    angle1, angle2, vel1, vel2, h01, h02, time = getInputs()
    cball1 = Projectile(angle1, vel1, h01)
    cball2 = Projectile(angle2, vel2, h02)
    tracker_cball1 = Tracker(win, cball1)
    tracker_cball2 = Tracker(win, cball2)

    while True:
        if cball1.getY() <= 0:    #<---ball 1
            cball1.reset(60, 60, 10)
        else:
            cball1.update(time)
            tracker_cball1.update()

        if cball2.getY() <= 0:    #<---ball 2
            cball2.reset(30, 60, 10)
        else:
            cball2.update(time)
            tracker_cball2.update()

if __name__ == '__main__' : main()
```

Thank you!, I am a big noob at coding at the moment. Much appreciated!

Comment: "I have no idea on how to make the ball follow instead of continuously printing circles to Track the movement of the ball." You are drawing the ball in update in the class Tracker. Rather than instantiate a new Circle every time, you need to make an object Circle and give it an update function that changes the x and y of self

Comment: does a.undraw() work? it kinda works. but its jumpy

Comment: You could but that doesn't really follow the requirement of "Instead of drawing the circle, move the circle" and "instead of continuously printing circles". It sounds like they only want you to make one circle, then move it. Not continuously make new circles and delete the previous one.